# Autocorrelation function with non-zero padding in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need to compute peak value of autocorrelation function(ACF) for a noisy image. In the computation of the ACF, I need to consider the end effects. Padding the ends of the array with zero is not appropriate in my work, as this will exclude the contribution of the nonoverlapping ends to the value of the ACF(so I can’t use xcorr2). Instead, it is suggested that the ends are padded with either the average value of the image, or the image is wrapped around, but only the N2 values contained within the original image boundary are counted so as to preserve the total energy content of the image. How can I write MATLAB code for this non-zero padding ACF?

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
A=randn(100); %noisy image

[i,j]=size(A);
border = 10;
B=ones([i+2*border,j+2*border]).*mean(A(:)); %put mean value of A in B
B(border+1:end-border,border+1:end-border)=A; %put A in centre of B
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.But I didn't understand why do you consider border=10 (ACF is a matrix with size [i*2-1, j*2-1])?

Comment: I do not calculate the ACF, but just pad the image with a border of 10 pixels. Please show how far you got yourself and people can point you in the right direction.

Comment: That's right. I know you just showed padding, but I thought that you did it according to ACF size of the image,and it made me confused.Thanks again.